# Extract pattern from string, strip text, convert to numeric and sum in R data.table?

Tags: regex, r, data.table, sapply

I have a (100k rows) data.table mydata with one of the column that looks like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

mdata <- data.table(A = c("17M1I26M570M20S1M", "17M1I260M570M20S1M"))
```

How do I efficiently - preferably in 1 line of code - pull out all numbers that precede the M's (they can be varying digits long), convert them to numeric and find their sum.

I have managed to do this with 3 rounds the sapply function, and creating some additional columns which I don't need:

```
mdata$c <- sapply(mydata[, A], function(x) unlist(str_extract_all(x, "\\d+M")))
mdata$c2 <-sapply(mydata[, c], function(x) unlist(as.numeric(gsub( "M", "",x))))
mdata$c3 <- sapply(mydata[,c2], function(x) sum(x))
```

Is there a cleaner,computationally more efficient way to do this?

Comment: You did not provide reproducible example so here is pseudo code answer in comment :) `f = function(x) unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, "M"),`[[`,1L))` then `dt[, .(col = f(col))]`, sum shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @jangorecki Edited to reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a function to grab the sum of numbers appearing before all instances of the letter M from the string, then create a column in your `data.table`.

Example code below:

```
# Load data.table and stringr packages
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

# Data provided in the question
mydata <- data.table(A = c("17M1I26M570M20S1M", "17M1I260M570M20S1M"))

# Function to grab the sum of numbers before the letter M in a string
sum_before_m <- function(x) {
  # Grab all numbers that appear before M
  matches <- str_match_all(x, "\\d+(?=M)")
  # Grab the matches column in the list, transform to numeric, then sum
  sapply(matches, function(y) sum(as.numeric(y)))
}

# Run the function for the column A
mydata[, c := sum_before_m(A)]

mydata
#                     A   c
# 1:  17M1I26M570M20S1M 614
# 2: 17M1I260M570M20S1M 848
```

**Edit:** Changed regex using @thelatemail's suggestion in comments for more efficient matching.

Comment: Using `str_match_all(x, "\\d+(?=M)")` will remove the need to subset later, and will store less data in the intermediate `matches` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidy way to do it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)
library(rex)

regex_1 = 
  rex(capture(digits),
      capture(letter) )

data = 
  data_frame(
    a = c("17M1I26M570M20S1M", 
          "17M1I260M570M20S1M") ) 

key = 
  data %>%
  select(a) %>%
  distinct %>%
  mutate(match_list = 
           a %>%
           stri_extract_all_regex(regex_1) ) %>%
  unnest(match_list) %>%
  extract(match_list,
          c("number", "letter"),
          regex_1) %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(order = 1:n(),
         number = as.numeric(number))

key %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(number)) %>%
  right_join(data)
```